# OPNsense 19.1 removes root's authorized_keys when reboot / shutdown+turn on

Tags: freebsd, openssh

I have an OPNsense 19.1 virtual firewall, which is based on FreeBSD 11.2 HBSD (HardenedBSD).

I added it to Ansible Server inventory (with the right configurations), and once copied the PK to that BSD /root/.ssh/authorized_keys, I can connect to it (yes, running commands as root, it is in an isolated training environment).

The issue is that **when I reboot or turn off and on the machine, that authorized_keys file disappears**.

The file permissions are 600 (-rw-------).

Do you know why this happens and how to solve it? As far as I could see, in a normal FreeBSD I think there's no problem in having authorized_keys file in the root account...

Comment: Could it be that a root home is mounted as `tmpfs`? Run `mount` without arguments to check.

Comment: I already checked that, it is not, indeed, other files I edit in /root remain there, and even the .ssh/known_hosts file

Answer (score 1):

To solve the issue, I'm afraid, you'll have to fight OPNsense 19.1 and find out how OPNsense handles roots authorized_keys.

> The issue is that when I reboot or turn off and on the machine, that authorized_keys file disappears.

But there is an option to ssh as a non-root user and *sudo su*. This is a better practice especially with Ansible. Ansible needs the remote user to use */bin/sh*. By default FreeBSD root uses */bin/csh*. Ansible best practice is to ssh as a *remote_user* and [escalate privilege](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html) (become: yes) to root (become_user: root).